# dependent pattern matching and kind of inversion

Tags: coq

The stack definition and a test function to work with it are defined below. (Maybe) only the nicety is that I need 2-levels of types (see in code). The code works (example can be compiled).

```ml
Require Import Coq.Lists.List.
Import List.ListNotations.

Inductive type1 : Set :=
| Unit1 : type1
| Option1 : type1 -> type1.

Inductive type2 : type1 -> Set :=
| Unit2 : type2 Unit1
| Option2 {t} :
    type2 t -> type2 (Option1 t).

Definition stack_t := list type1.

Inductive stack : stack_t -> Set :=
| Head {t ts} :
  type2 t ->
  stack ts ->
  stack (t :: ts)
| Empty :
  stack [].

Record stacks (s1 : stack_t) : Set := Build {
  st1 : stack s1;                                             
}.

Definition test {ts_inp} (st_inp : stack ts_inp) : option (stacks ts_inp) :=
  match st_inp in stack ts_inp_cp1 with
  | @Head Unit1 ts_rest Unit2 st_rest as st_c1 =>
      Some (Build (Unit1::ts_rest) (Head Unit2 st_rest))
  | _ => None
  end.
```

Adding the next `test1` definition rises an error

```ml
Definition test1 {ts_inp} (st_inp : stack ts_inp) : option (stacks ts_inp) :=
  match st_inp in stack ts_inp_cp1 with
  | @Head Unit1 ts_rest Unit2 st_rest as st =>
      Some (Build (Unit1::ts_rest) (Head Unit2 st_rest))
  | @Head (Option1 t1) ts_rest (@Option2 t11 t2) st_rest as st' =>
      Some (Build ((Option1 t1)::ts_rest) (Head (Option2 t2) st_rest))
  | _ => None
  end.
```

According to the error message, `coq` is not able to  see that `t1` and `t11` is the same type.

How to convince the coq that `t1` and `t11` are the same in the test1 definition?

---

UPD.
This definition looks to me similar to what I would like to have (this does not compiles)

````
Definition computeType (T : Type) (t : type1) : Type :=
  match t with
  | Option1 _ => T
  | _ => unit
  end.

Definition test1 {ts_inp} (st_inp : stack ts_inp) : option (stacks ts_inp) :=
  match st_inp in stack ts_inp_cp1 with
  | @Head Unit1 ts_rest Unit2 st_rest as st =>
      Some (Build (Unit1::ts_rest) (Head Unit2 st_rest))
  | @Head (Option1 t1 as t11) ts_rest (Option2 t2 as t22) st_rest as st' =>
      match t11, t22 in type2 (Option1 t21) return type2 t11 -> @computeType (option (stacks (t11 :: ts_rest))) t11 with
      | Option1 _, Option2 _ => fun x => Some (Build _ (Head x st_rest))
      | _, _ => fun x => tt
      end t22
  | _ => None
  end.
```
````

Comment: Could you please give a more specific title?

Comment: I don't see why "[you] need 2-levels of types". You're defining a singleton type corresponding exactly to the underlying one.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Just to make sure I can use terminology correctly: which of them (`type1` or `type2`) is `singleton` and which one is `underlying`. @gallais

Answer (score 1):

this one works

```
Definition computeType (ts : stack_t) (t : type1) : Type :=
  match t with
  | Option1 _ => option (stacks ts)
  | _ => unit
  end.

Definition test1 {ts_inp} (st_inp : stack ts_inp) : option (stacks ts_inp) :=
  match st_inp in stack ts_inp_cp1 with
  | @Head Unit1 ts_rest Unit2 st_rest as st =>
      Some (Build (Unit1::ts_rest) (Head Unit2 st_rest))
  | @Head (Option1 t1 as t11) ts_rest (Option2 t2 as t22) st_rest as st' =>
      match t11, t22 in type2 (Option1 t21) return type2 t11 -> computeType (t11 :: ts_rest) t11 with
      | _, _ => fun x => Some (Build _ (Head x st_rest))
      end t22
  | _ => None
  end.
```